# NSURLConnection cancellation callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsconnection

Is it possible to catch `NSURLConnection cancel` using a callback?

If I'm using this code

```
-(void) pleaseStopDownload {
cancelled = YES;
    [conn cancel];
    conn = nil;
    [self myUpdateUImessage];
}
```

from time to `myUpdateUImessage` is called before this callback

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
if (!cancelled) {
//this code inside brackets suddenly is calling:(
//not always but from time to time
    summ += data.length;
    if (_progressHandler != nil)
        _progressHandler(data, summ, max);
} else {
return;
}
}
```

So the User interface is not updated properly! That is, the final UI is shown than progress UI.

**EDIT**
the problem was about

```
NSOperationQueue *tempQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[conn setDelegateQueue:tempQueue];
```

correct `NSQueue` is     `NSOperationQueue *tempQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to catch NSURLConnection cancel using a callback?

No.

From the official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/cancel):

> After this method is called, the connection makes no further delegate method calls.

This means you should handle the UI cleanup as soon as you call `cancel` and not rely on the `_cancelled` variable because `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` is not expected to be invoked anymore.

What I advice, is to call a **cleanup method** from your cancellation code:

```
-(void) pleaseStopDownload {
    [conn cancel];
    conn = nil;
    [self handleCancelledDownload];
}
```